# CodeIgniter datatables ajax url can't be found. Routing problem?

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

I can't find out how to set the url for datatables in a view. I think it's a routing problem because datatables can use the function in the controller Pages.php but not in the controller Djur.php.

My structure is:

```
-application
--controllers
---Djur.php
---Pages.php
--models
---Djur_model
--views
---djur
----mina_djur (1)
---pages
----mina_djur (2)
```

Both controllers include the same function:

```
         public function __construct() {
                Parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model("djur_model");
            }
            public function djurlista()
                 {

                      // Datatables Variables
                      $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
                      $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
                      $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));


                      $djur = $this->djur_model->get_djur();

                      $data = array();

                      foreach($djur->result() as $r) {

                           $data[] = array(
                                $r->ani_se_number,
                                $r->ani_individual_number,
                                $r->ani_gender,
                                $r->ani_date_of_birth,
                                $r->ani_race,
                               $r->ani_name,
                               $r->ani_mother,
                               $r->ani_father
                           );
                      }

                      $output = array(
                           "draw" => $draw,
                             "recordsTotal" => $djur->num_rows(),
                             "recordsFiltered" => $djur->num_rows(),
                             "data" => $data
                        );

                      echo json_encode($output);
                      exit();
                 }
```

The view mina_djur.php in folder djur (1) has url specified like this:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#mina_djur').DataTable(
                    {
                        "ajax": {
                            url : "<?php echo site_url("djur/djurlista") ?>",
                            type : 'GET'
                        },
                    }


                    );
                });
            </script>
```

When loading the page localhost/djur/mina_djur everything shows correct except that datatables can't load data (Ajax-error message). The developer tools in browser shows 500 error for XHR.

However,

When loading the page localhost/mina_djur (view located in folder pages (2)) datatables can get the data. In this file url is specified like:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#mina_djur').DataTable(
                    {
                        "ajax": {
                            url : "<?php echo site_url("pages/djurlista") ?>",
                            type : 'GET'
                        },
                    }


                    );
                });
            </script>
```

The fact that everything works if view is in folder pages instead of folder djur make me think the problem must be with routing when trying to get the function djurlista in the controller Djur.php from djur/mina_djur. Or by an error in the url in view.

My routes are:

```
$route['djur'] = 'djur/view/mina_djur';
$route['djur/(:any)'] = 'djur/view/$1';
$route['om'] = 'pages/view/om';
$route['mina_djur'] = 'pages/view/mina_djur'; // Required to make the view in folder pages work
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Why can't the view *views/djur/mina_djur* use the function djurlista in controller Djur.php?

Answer (score 0):

You should put the most specific routes on top. So swap the order of these two:

```
$route['djur'] = 'djur/view/mina_djur';
$route['djur/(:any)'] = 'djur/view/$1';
```

like this:

```
$route['djur/(:any)'] = 'djur/view/$1';
$route['djur'] = 'djur/view/mina_djur';
```

Comment: Thanks @SurfMan for your answer. Unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem. /mina_djur still gets data from database but /djur/mina_djur does not.